# Convert a type name to the actual type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.8, typescript1.5

Suppose we have the following enum

```
enum PrimayValType {
  "string",
  "boolean",
  "integer",
  "float"
}
```

Now i want to write a function that inputs a `Buffer` and a parameter of type `PrimaryValType` and converts the buffer based on the `PrimaryValType`. How to write such a function in Typescript?

```
function f(b: Buffer, t: PrimayValType): ??? {
    // converts b to a literal based on t
}

const b = Buffer.from('test', 'utf-8');
f(b, PrimayValType.string) // should be of type string
```

Comment: you could define overloads like `function f(b: Buffer, t: PrimayValType.string): string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the return type of your function as a mapped type. First, define `PrimaryValType` as a mapping from the string literals to the actual types:

```js
type PrimaryValType = {
    "string": string,
    "boolean": boolean,
    "integer": number,
    "float": number,
}
```

Then given a string of type `K extends keyof PrimaryValType`, we can map it to the correct return type using the mapped type `PrimaryValType[K]`.

To parse the input as the right type, you can switch on the type-string:

```js
function parse<K extends keyof PrimaryValType>(s: string, t: K): PrimaryValType[K] {
    switch (t) {
        case "integer": return parseInt(s) as PrimaryValType[K];
        case "float":   return parseFloat(s) as PrimaryValType[K];
        case "boolean": return (s === "true") as PrimaryValType[K];
        case "string":  s as PrimaryValType[K];

        default: throw new Error("Illegal t: " + t);
    }
}
```

The type assertions are needed because Typescript can't tell that when `t === 'integer'` then `K` can't be `'string'`, for example. The code can be neatened by storing the parser functions in an object, as in @kmos.w's answer:

```js
const parsers: { [K in keyof PrimaryValType]: (s: string) => PrimaryValType[K] } = {
    "integer": parseInt,
    "float":   parseFloat,
    "boolean": s => s === "true",
    "string":  s => s,
};

function parse<K extends keyof PrimaryValType>(s: string, t: K): PrimaryValType[K] {
    return parsers[t](s) as PrimaryValType[K];
}
```

The type assertion is still needed, for the same reason.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYEM4gGooDYBVzQC8UA3gFBSVQBEAzsIgHYDm1AXFPU8wDQVXUARgHth2CCkbsoIsRMZ8qNBI2ARmEONMYBXJIM2KBAM2zCUwbXoNw+AXzJljOxgGNgCYYyhg0tCACMADwA0lAQAB5qjAAmtFAA1hAgwsawiKjoWHgEAHwAFLQcXCq8UMAcIQCUHPDIaJg4+JAA2iEAuqT8lLQA7gjArgAWUPnAVV1KSq4o-sqq6prScBDAOnDevnD+AJKqhROz6fVZTQRt7QDc3VMzc9Sm5pYclCtrGz5+EABiZhYHUCOdUyjRyrQ61ymVDu0CEonEkmWq3W3kKUEIGJoDB0EGoh3iwIa2WaEAukKhUBhNBKLGknEBBIyRLO4KujgpUBiEGMKB02Aq5SGcGEvSgjAgooAonBhXB8tQdthxMwcOUONQoABqcpVcmUBwOMiuLz0T7bTRFUhQNpQFSJZKpY4g4kEdocQrFBilCaEXJO5lg0kdKB2dGTAQqNQaLQcLa7VRGSgPP7PM3+X5PRM0WQIqTFdF++IY4jUbG4rN0L20-O+zj2a5OFzuTybL4AJlC4SiEFi8SSKTShNOgYKlppZQF1VqTOHJIu4deyI+cYtLWA7QBQJnoLnELIDiAA)

Answer (score 2):

[1]. Advice: Enums in typescript are used to define named constants. So it is better to qualify the string literals by names e.g.

```js
enum PrimayValType {
  STRING = 'string',
  BOOLEAN = 'boolean',
  INTEGER = 'integer',
  FLOAT   = 'float',
}
```

[2]. Try this:

```
function f(b: Buffer, t: PrimayValType=PrimayValType.STRING): number | string | boolean {
  const value = b.toString('utf-8');
  switch (t) {
    case PrimayValType.BOOLEAN:
      const isBool = /true|false/.test(value);
      if (!isBool) {
        throw new TypeError(`${value} is invalid for a boolean type`);
      }
      return /true/.test(value);
    case PrimayValType.INTEGER:
    case PrimayValType.FLOAT:
      const isNaN = Number.isNaN(value);
      if (isNaN) {
        throw new TypeError(`${value} is invalid for a numeric type`);
      }
      return t === PrimayValType.INTEGER ? Number.parseInt(value) : Number.parseFloat(value);
    default:
      return value;
  }
}

essertEqual(f(Buffer.from("3.14", "utf-8"), PrimayValType.FLOAT), 3.14);
assertEqual(f(Buffer.from("3.14", "utf-8"), PrimayValType.INTEGER), 3);
assertTrue(f(Buffer.from("true", "utf-8")));
```

Revised answer. The Typescript way. (I haven't tested this):

```js
const parseBool = (value: string) => {
    if (!/true|false/.test(value)) throw new TypeError(`${value} is invalid for a boolean type`);
    return /true/.test(value);
};


type PrimType = "string" | "boolean" | "integer" | "float";
type Convert<T> = (str: string) => T;
type Convertors<T> = { [t in PrimType]: Convert<T> };

const convertors: Convertors<number|string|boolean> = {
    "integer": parseInt,
    "float": parseFloat,
    "boolean": parseBool,
    "string": (str) => str,
};

const f = (b: Buffer, t: PrimType) => convertors[t](b.toString('utf-8'));
```